# How to download .pdf files from pubmed

Tags: curl

I can't download `.pdf` files from http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles, I already have some document IDs such as PMC3404089.

I tried to issue the following command:

```
curl -o file.pdf http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3404089
```

The command downloaded a file, `file.pdf`, but it is an empty file.

Answer (score 2):

The pdf from your link is here : http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3404089/pdf/pone.0041450.pdf . There is a menu on the right called Formats, right click on the pdf, copy link location, then paste it as an argument to curl.